# How to safety switch 240VAC electronically?

Tags: mains

I am designing a circuit to control a baseboard heater.  I need to turn on and off the 240Volts that the heater runs on.  The problem is that both sides of the 240VAC are hot. Solid state relays only control one side of the line.  If I had a 240VAC and ground, no problem. But I have 2 120VAC lines 180 degrees out of phase. Every design i have run across is designed for single sided control. Anyone have any ideas?

I know this is possible as the old thermostat that controlled it, did control both sides of the supply.

Comment: So use two solid state relays. Or two single pole mechanical relays. Or a single double pole relay. Or a double pole contactor.

Comment: How much current do you switch?

Comment: _"I know this is possible as the old thermostat that controlled it, did control both sides of the supply."_ - how do you know this?

Comment: turning off one side breaks the circuit and turns off the heater

Comment: There is about 15A as measured by clamp-on meter from similar heater in next room. Measured voltage from other room thermostats is 0 on both sides when off. 120VAC to ground when on. Breaking one side would turn off heater, but other side would still be hot. Would like both sides off for safety.  I would prefer to use a electronic device and not a relay.  Had not thought about two solid state relays.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to use a 2-pole contactor to switch both the lines.

Here's the schematic.

[image]